# Which UUID has to be chosen for bluetooth connection on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, rfcomm

At the moment I'm developing a new Android application. I require Bluetooth for that app. Every time I want to connect two (paired) devices via the serversocket / socket system I'm not able to create a working socket. It always returns:

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

So my question is: Am I using an invalid UUID? If that's not the case. Do you have any other suggestions what might be wrong?

```
public Accept(BluetoothAdapter bt, BluetoothDevice device, Context context) {
            try {
                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
                try {
                    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00294F9B3423");
    //Here is the point when it doesn't work...
                    tmp = bt.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(context.getResources().getString(R.string.bt_string_for_profile_image), uuid);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                mmServerSocket = tmp;

                bt_device = device;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing accept statement here.
After listen your next statement should be tmp.accept(). This will solve your issue. So, your code should look like this:

```
    try { 
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00294F9B3423"); 
Bluetoothsocket clientSocket;
//Here is the point when it doesn't work... 
tmp = bt.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(context.getResources().getString(R.string.bt_string_for_profile_image), uuid); 
clientSocket = tmp.accept();
}
```

Also, one thing to note down here, accept function call is blocking code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your reply. But I'm sorry to say that this didn't solve my problem. I probably didn't give you enough code. My code looks basicall like the one you can see here: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAServer)  So I handle it as a Thread. And I call the accept()-Methode in the run() methode of that Thread.

Comment: But as soon as I call this methode bt.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(context.getResources().getString(R.string.bt_string_for_profile_image), uuid); the channel of thr serversocket is -1 so I think it must be a problem with this methode?

Comment: Ohhh.. I'm sorry I did not know your complete code... Now, first thing you can do here is to check the error code/ exception returned by listen function. This will help us to understand the reason for error. As I read the link provided by you, listen can throw exception in these cases only "on error, for example Bluetooth not available, or insufficient permissions, or channel in use. "

Comment: Also, can you try this UUID: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

Comment: I'm so happy to say that I somehow managed to solve my problem.. Sadly I can not really tell you how I managed it exactely.. But I really want to thank you for all the time you've used for me. Thank you soo much. In case I will come to another problem with my bluetooth application I will ask you again if that's alright with you, Again: thanks a lot.